# Relation between the coefficients in the different basis.

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

we can represent this polynomial $f$ in two basis, Monomial basis and hermite basis. How can we get the relationship between coefficients of $f$ in both the basis.

Is there any way to extend this result to functions defined as  $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ .